# Share states between two reducers (React +Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have these two reducers

```
const getPosts = (initialState = {posts: []}, action) => {...}

const createPost = (initialState = {post: null}, action) => {...}
```

where `getPosts` reducer puts the fetched posts performed by the associated action creator in the state variable `posts`, while `createPost` puts the created post in the state variable `post`. The action creator associated with the `createPost` stores the post into the database in the backend, and after storing the post in the database, I would like to update the posts on the page in the frontend from `getPosts` without fetching all the posts again from the database again because I already have all the posts in the state but the new one. So, what I am trying to do is to push the created post into the `posts` state variable, but both states are in different reducers. How can I push the `post` state variable's value into the `posts` state variable to achieve an update at the frontend without fetching all the posts again after each post creation?

Comment: You should get the state variable in the action, and send it in the payload to the other reducer. Use a middleware like `redux-thunk` or react-redux hooks

Answer (score 1):

When you dispatch the action that creates the new post, you can also dispatch an action that adds it to the `getPosts` reducer.

Alternatively, when the `POST` succeeds from creating the new `post in the db, you can then dispatch the action that adds it to the` getPosts` reducer.

Comment: I guess this is one way of doing it by using the `getState()` in the action creator to get the `posts` state variable and push the new post into it, and then put the modified `posts` again into the `getPosts` reducer, although I was thinking maybe a top-level reducer is a better solution, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Well, I guess, now that you mention it, if you only have `posts` and `post` state you're keeping track of, why not just put them both in the same reducer?

Comment: These are just sample reducers. I have many reducers for posts, if put together the reducer's state will be large and complex.

Comment: In Redux you can make a top level reducer with `combineReducers`: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers